# ubuntu 18.04 do not reconize monitor samsung19

Tags: display-resolution, samsung

I upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04 but the new release of ubuntu do not reconize my resolution 19x6 of the Samsung monitor. I could not change the resolution due the minimum/maximum size: 1024 x 768 ??. Need help.
This is de result of xrandr comand:

```
tomas@tomas-OEM:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  Samsung19 (0x2ac) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
```

And this the result of lshw command:

```
tomas@tomas-OEM:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] contraseña para tomas: 
  *-display NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versión: 10
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:fdf00000-fdf7ffff ioport:ff00(size=8) memoria:d0000000-dfffffff memoria:fda00000-fdafffff memoria:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: I must add the "nomodeset" option in the GRUB because Ubuntu do no run without this option, I do not know if this afect de vga controller.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:
1. Disable Wayland and enable Xorg (Wayland was my problem to boot ubuntu)
    https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
2. Eliminate the option "nomodeset" in the GRUB.

and Ubuntu run OK