# Xubuntu 20.04 not utilizing Radeon driver amdgpu correctly

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, lightdm, radeon, wayland

Background: Running a new (refurbished) Acer Swift 3 SF314-42-R6T7 with Radeon graphics, Xubuntu 20.04 Focal, recent installation, kernel 5.4.0-60-generic

I have essentially the same problem as in this resolved question: [ubuntu 18.04 do not reconize monitor samsung19](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075646/ubuntu-18-04-do-not-reconize-monitor-samsung19) However, I am running Xubuntu, which uses LightDM as a display manager. If disabling Wayland in favor of Xorg is the solution I need, I don't know how to do that with LightDM.

I tried installing the proprietary AMD drivers for Ubuntu, as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation) last night. Immediately had to boot into recovery and undo that.

Output of some commands I learned in that process (sorry for the Spanish):

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: VGA compatible controller
       producto: Renoir
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versión: c3
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:b0000000-bfffffff memoria:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memoria:c0600000-c067ffff

$ lsmod | grep amd
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
kvm_amd                98304  0
amdgpu               4579328  0
ccp                    86016  1 kvm_amd
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_amd
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
drm                   491520  4 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm

$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 20.2.6
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 7388MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get my amdgpu driver working, possibly by disabling Wayland?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the [driver installation package](https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-20.45-1188099-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz) from [Radeon](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45) and ran `./amdgpu-install` per their instructions in `./doc/index.html`. Gave it a restart and everything is now just fine.